# How to sort lines of text by other lines of text as keys?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, command-line-interface

Basically the equivalent of "sort-by" method in CLI.

A sample input file (`file1.txt`):

```
one
three
five
eleven
thirteen
sixteen
```

Another input file (`file2.txt`, which lists length of corresponding line in `file1.txt`):

```
3
5
4
6
8
7
```

Desired output (sort lines in `file1.txt` by lines in `file2.txt`, in this case numerically; or in other words, sort lines in `file1.txt` by the line's length):

```
one
five
three
eleven
sixteen
thirteen
```

I've created a [simple Perl script](https://metacpan.org/pod/sort-by-lines) to do this. Sample usage:

```
% sort-by-lines file1.txt file2.txt
% sort-by-lines /etc/passwd <(perl -nE'say length' /etc/passwd)
```

But was wondering if a combination of more basic Unix commands (`sort`, `cut`, etc) can also do the same in a comparably simple fashion.

Comment: You should include some same-length lines in your input and explicitly state/show if their input order must be preserved in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you just trying to sort a file by the length of each line? With standard tools in any shell on any UNIX box that'd be:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{print length(), NR, $0}' file | sort -k1,2n | cut -f3-
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
other stuff
text
foo
stuff
bar

$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print length(), NR, $0}' file | sort -k1,2n | cut -f3-
foo
bar
text
stuff
other stuff
```

If that's not it then please edit your question to clarify what it is you're trying to do and what your actual question is.

---

Update - given the input you added to your question:

```
$ paste file2.txt file1.txt | sort -k1,2n | cut -f2-
one
five
three
eleven
sixteen
thirteen
```

Note that that won't necessarily preserve the order of lines of the same length - you'd need to add the GNU `-s` ("stable") option to `sort` to do that:

```
paste file2.txt file1.txt | sort -s -k1,2n | cut -f2-
```

or do this which is bash only:

```
paste file2.txt <(cat -n file1.txt) | sort -k1,2n | cut -f3-
```

or this which is portable to all shells/Unixes:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR], FNR, $0}' file2.txt file1.txt | sort -k1,2n | cut -f3-
```

or do something with an explicit temp file or a here document.

Comment: Ah yes, so the solution is simply `sort -k`. Thanks!